# Python seem not to remember value from first IF

Tags: python

I extract data from Excel file every minutes. I want to create a separate df for data extracted at 12:30 and 12:31. I start running at 12:00. At 12:`30`, dataframe at_12_`30` is created and exported.

At 12:31, at the line print(at_12_`30`) (thirty), python give error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'at_12_30' referenced before assignment`

Clearly, the at_12_30 is there. Please help.

```
# Step1: open Excel file 
# ....

# Step 2: Import value from excel file

def download_data():
    #get data
    data = ws.Range("A1:C5").Value
    #convert to df
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
    
    # Mark time of export:
    extract_data_time = datetime.datetime.now() ;


    if extract_data_time = extract_data_time.replace(hour=12, minute=30):  
      
        at_12_30=df
        print(at_12_30)
        at_12_30.to_csv(fr'C:\Users\at_12_30.csv', index=False)
               
    elif extract_data_time = extract_data_time.replace(hour=12, minute=31)::
        at_12_31=df
        
        print(at_12_30) # IT RETURNS ERROR HERE
        print(at_12_31)
        at_12_31.to_csv(fr'C:\Users\at_12_31.csv', index=False)
        
        #Merge 12_30 and 12_31
        #....   
        
    else:

        df.to_csv(fr'C:\data.csv', index=False)

    time.sleep(60)
        
schedule.every().minute.at(':59').do(download_data)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The code you've shared does not reference the variable `pre_market` anywhere. Show all of the code where this variable is defined/referenced!

Comment: Perhaps you've posted the wrong error message? It seems like the `UnboundLocalError` is really complaining about the variable `at_12_30`, which is not surprising, because that variable is only defined if you enter the `if` branch.

Comment: Either `if` or `elif` is executed, not both. So a variable that's assigned inside `if` is not available inside `elif`.

Comment: Yes, in this context, the error message is: ```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'at_12_30' referenced before assignment``` . Post udated

Comment: @Barmar. I thought that after the first round, the dataframe at_12_30 is created (in the ```first if```). Then it should be stored in the environment so in the ```elif``` we can call it out.

Comment: These are local variables, they don't persist between calls to the function.

Comment: Oh I see, the define function is the cause. Thanks. I try to declare a df name ``` at_12_30``` outside the function() and concat it to the df. Still not working. Is there any solution to my problem?